# How to run my code 10,000 times and keep track of how many times each player wins?

Tags: python

I am trying to make my code run 10,000 times. it needs to run 10,000 times.  Keep track of how many times each player wins, how many times each player scores the bonus, and how many times all three players earned the bonus. I have no clue how to get this to work and have been trying to figure it out. can anyone show me how to do this? I will post the code below.

```
 #Part3
 #Create a simulation of the game that runs 10,000 times.  
 #Keep track of how many times each player wins, how many times each player scores the bonus
 #how many times all three players earned the bonus.
    import random       
    Spin1 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
    print('Spin1', Spin1)
    if (Spin1) > 94 :
      Spin2 = 0
    if (Spin1) == 100 :
      Spin2 = 0
      print('Player 1 spun 100! They have won $1,000!')
    if (Spin1) < 94:
      Spin2 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('Spin2', Spin2)
    SpinTotal1 = (Spin1 + Spin2)
    print('Player 1 Score = ',SpinTotal1)
    if (SpinTotal1) > 100 :
      SpinTotal1 = 0
      print('Player 1 spun above 100. They have been reset to',SpinTotal1)
    import random       
    Spin1 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
    print('Spin1', Spin1)
    if (Spin1) > 94 :
      Spin2 = 0
    if (Spin1) == 100 :
      Spin2 = 0
      print('Player 2 spun 100! They have won $1,000!')
    if (Spin1) < 94:
      Spin2 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('Spin2', Spin2)
    SpinTotal2 = (Spin1 + Spin2)
    print('Player 2 Score = ',SpinTotal2)
    if (SpinTotal2) > 100 :
      SpinTotal2 = 0
      print('Player 2 spun above 100. They have been reset to',SpinTotal2)
    import random       
    Spin1 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
    print('Spin1', Spin1)
    if (Spin1) > 95 :
      Spin2 = 0
    if (Spin1) == 100 :
      Spin2 = 0
      print('Player 3 spun 100! They have won $1,000!')
    if (Spin1) < 95 :
      Spin2 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('Spin2', Spin2)
    SpinTotal3 = (Spin1 + Spin2)
    print('Player 3 Score = ',SpinTotal3)
    if (SpinTotal3) > 100 :
      SpinTotal3 = 0
      print('Player 3 spun above 100. You have been reset to',SpinTotal3)
    if (SpinTotal1 == SpinTotal2) :
      SpinOff3 = 0
      print('Tie! This results in a Spin Off between Player 1 and 2')
      SpinOff1 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('P1 Spin off score =', SpinOff1)
      SpinOff2 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('P2 Spin off score =', SpinOff2)
    if (SpinTotal1 == SpinTotal3) :
      SpinOff2 = 0 
      print('Tie! This results in a Spin Off between Player 1 and 3')
      SpinOff1 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('P1 Spin off score =', SpinOff1)
      SpinOff3 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('P3 Spin off score =', SpinOff3)
    if (SpinTotal2 == SpinTotal3) :
      SpinOff1 = 0
      print('Tie! This results in a Spin Off between Player2 and 3')
      SpinOff2 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('P2 Spin off score =', SpinOff2)
      SpinOff3 = (random.randint(1,20)*5)
      print('P3 Spin off score =', SpinOff3)
    if (SpinTotal1 > SpinTotal2 and SpinTotal1 > SpinTotal3 and SpinTotal1 > SpinOff2 and SpinTotal1 > SpinOff3):
      print('Player 1 is the winner, will recieve $10,000 prize!')
      if (SpinTotal1) == 100 :
        print('Your total prize is $11,000! Congratulations!')
    if (SpinTotal2 > SpinTotal1 and SpinTotal2 >SpinTotal3 and SpinTotal2 > SpinOff1 and SpinTotal2 > SpinOff3):
      print('Player 2 is the winner, will recieve $10,000!')
      if (SpinTotal2) == 100 :
        print('Your total prize is $11,000! Congratulations!')
    if (SpinTotal3 > SpinTotal1 and SpinTotal3 > SpinTotal2 and SpinTotal3 > SpinOff1 and SpinTotal3 > SpinOff2):
      print('Player 3 is the winner, will recieve $10,000!')
      if (SpinTotal3) == 100 :
        print('Your total prize is $11,000! Congratulations!')
    if (SpinOff1 > SpinTotal1 and SpinOff1 > SpinTotal2 and SpinOff1 > SpinTotal3 and SpinOff1 > SpinOff2 and SpinOff1 > SpinOff3):
      print('Player 1 is the winner, $10,000!')
      if (SpinOff1) == 100 :
        print('Your total prize is $11,000! Congratulations!')
    if (SpinOff2 > SpinTotal1 and SpinOff2 > SpinTotal2 and SpinOff2 > SpinTotal3 and SpinOff2 > SpinOff1 and SpinOff2 > SpinOff3):
      print('Player 2 is the winner, $10,000!')
      if (SpinOff2) == 100 :
        print('Your total prize is $11,000! Congratulations!')
    if (SpinOff3 > SpinTotal1 and SpinOff3 > SpinTotal2 and SpinOff3 > SpinTotal3 and SpinOff3 > SpinOff1 and SpinOff3 > SpinOff2):
      print('Player 3 is the winner, $10,000!')
      if (SpinOff3) == 100 :
        print('Your total prize is $11,000! Congratulations!')
```

Comment: You should look into for loops https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: Could you explain what the rules of the game are?  The code is somewhat difficult to read.

Comment: Have you tried working through a tutorial? Any tutorial should cover loops in just the first few lessons.

Comment: As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, it's not really clear what your question is. However, I'd really suggest you go through a Python tutorial, because there are several things (like indenting two spaces) which are really odd and make it hard for others to read and understand your code.

Comment: When asking question, it's important to only provide only a [mre] that illustrates the issue being asked about, not your entire program.

Comment: The most ideal way would be using a for loop and incrementing an array of 4 elements to track the count.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your code a function with the required input variables. Once you have such function, run in in a loop and store the output of each run in a list for later evaluation:

```
def my_game_function(var1, ..., varn):
    ...
    return output1, output2, ..., outputn

all_outputs = []
for i in range(10000):
    output = my_game_function(var1, ..., varn)
    all_outputs.extend(output)
    # if your function outputs a single value, use append
    # all_outputs.append(output)
```

Comment: how would you go about doing that?

Comment: Replace your print statements and assign the output strings to a variable, and at the end, return the value of that variable after going through all your logic.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a similar game, with less rules, just takes the highest score of all the roles and rewards that player with a value depending on the score they get and keeps track of every score and win.

This is the complete code but i will suggest you to copy function by function and testing what is actually doing and get an idea of how to split a complex task.

```
import random

class Player:
    id = None
    n_wins = 0
    n_score = 0

class Game:

    n_plays = 0

    def score_value(self):
        if self.winner_score == 100:
            value = 10000
        elif self.winner_score >= 75:
            value = 1000
        else:
            value = 100
        return value

    def print_score(self):
        print('Game {0}, player {1} won ${2}!'.format(
            self.n_plays, self.winner_id + 1, self.score_value())
        )

    def play_for(self, n, show=True):
        for i in range(n):
            self.make_play()
            if show:
                self.print_score()

    def play(self):
        self.make_play()
        self.print_score()

    def make_play(self):
        play_res = []
        for i in range(self.n_player):
            play_res.append(random.randint(1, 20) * 5)

        winer = play_res.index(max(play_res))
        self.players[winer].n_wins += 1

        for i in range(self.n_player):
            self.players[i].n_score += play_res[i]

        self.winner_id = self.players[winer].id
        self.winner_score = max(play_res)
        self.n_plays += 1

    def add_players(self, n_players):
        self.n_player = n_players
        for i in range(n_players):
            self.players.append(Player())
            self.players[i].id = i

    def get_player(self, index):
        return self.players[index - 1]

    def __init__(self):
        self.players = []
        self.n_player = 0

        self.winner_id = 0
        self.winner_score = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.add_players(3)
    game.play()
    game.play_for(9999, show=False)
    game.play_for(5)

    player_2 = game.get_player(2)
    print('Player 2 won {0} times and has a score of {1}'.format(
        player_2.n_wins, player_2.n_score)
    )
```